# Edit php file on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

When I did run my web site on my old server, I launched Transmit on my Mac (OS X 10.11.6), connected to my server, Control-Click-Open the remote php file, made the fix and save. The file got updated on the server in a second. That was great to run some php/mysql/google_service test that I can't run locally.

Now I have just moved my project on an Amazon server, AWS. Every time I need to run a test (for example on the S3_Bucket, that I can't run locally), or modify a variable, change a flag... I have to do it on my local php/html/java/css/apis project, zip it, upload it via the Elastic Beanstalk panel, wait about half a minute, then run it. I have found no way to edit a single file in an easy way (Open, Write, Save) as I did before through Transmit. I can't go ahead this way. It's wasting my time.

Do you know any better way to develop/test/run my project on AWS?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Docker?

https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/04/aws-elastic-beanstalk-cli-supports-local-development-and-testing-for-docker-containers/

Or use MAMP?

https://www.mamp.info/en/

Comment: Thank you byumark, I am going to take a look at the Docker. As far as MAMP, I have already installed php and MySQL on my local machine. But from the localhost I can't test services as Google Map, Facebook login, the different AWS buckets, the AWS local variables... I will read its features. I'll let you know.

Comment: Thanks for the update, @Leonardo. I believe you can test AWS services locally. You just have to use access keys and the AWS PHP SDK or CLI.  Not sure about google and facebook, but it should be possible. It may be worth looking into, because local development and testing is really nice.

Comment: I have installed MAMP PRO. My first impression is not good. When I click on a php file to edit, the colored spinning wheel runs for about 1 minute. It loads the whole document, while with TextWrangler it's immediate. Too bad. Then, on the text editor there is not a popUp menu listing all the php functions I wrote within the php document. So it's a pain to locate and go to edit the wanted function. Too bad. I have to click on the Editor icon then Control-click on the php file in the left list and edit the file with TextWrangler. That's not a good solution.